# Tests with multiple scenarios and multiple parameters

Tags: linux, api, yaml, continuous-testing, taurus

I'm trying to write a taurus test in .yml that will include multiple scenarios (like ping host request, change hostname on machine, install java,..).
Every scenario has a request that is an API call, with url, POST method and body.

### Problem 1:

Every scenario should be developed in a separate files, and tests should be called this way: "bzt scenario_1.yml scenario_2.yml,...".

**Is there a solution like include_scenario, import?**

For example in Ansible there is include_tasks, so I can just call other .yml scripts and everything works great.

### Problem 2:

How can I create some kind of loop for body, so that my API request will use different parameters for each distribution. Cause I'm trying to write a test with high concurrency that will for example ping, change hostname and install Java for Ubuntu, Debian, Centos,..

Current code sample:

```
---

execution:
- iterations: 2
  concurrency: 1000
  ramp-up: 20m

  scenarios:

   ping:
    requests:
    - url: http://127.0.0.1:12121/ping/
      method: POST
      label: ping
      body-file: ./vars/"{{ping}}"
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
      parameters:
        - /debian/ping.json
        - /ubuntu/ping.json
        - /centos7/ping.json

   changeHostname:
    requests:
    - url: http://127.0.0.1:12121/changeHostname/
      method: POST
      label: ping
      body-file: ./vars/"{{change_hostname}}"
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
      parameters:
        - /debian/hostnameDto.json
        - /ubuntu/hostnameDto.json
        - /centos7/hostnameDto.json

   changeRootPassword:
    requests:
    - url: http://127.0.0.1:12121/changeRootPassword/
      method: POST
      label: ping
      body-file: ./varss/"{{change_root_password}}"
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
      parameters:
        - /debian/changeRootPasswordDto.json
        - /ubuntu/changeRootPasswordDto.json
        - /centos7/changeRootPasswordDto.json

reporting:
  - module: console
  - module: final-stats

settings:
  check-interval: 5s
  default-executor: jmeter

provisioning: local
```

Thank you.

Comment: note how few followers there are for the `taurus` tag. You'll probably do better finding the dedicated dev/support forums for this project. Good luck.

Comment: You're right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in YAML to include other config files:

```
included-configs:  
  - additional-local-file.yml
  - another-config.yml
```

http://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#Included-Configs